# How do I pass a file path to a function instead of the contents of the file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, path, function

I'm using bash shell on Ubuntu Linux.  I have this in my script

```
output_file=create_test_results_file "$TFILE1"
```

Through echo statements, I have verified that the value of $TFILE1 is a file path, e.g.

```
/tmp/run_tests.sh1.7381.tmp
```

But when I run my script, somehow the contents of the file are being passed to my function, whose contents are

```
#!/bin/bash

create_test_results_file () {
        RESULTS_INPUT_FILE=$1
        OUTPUT_FILE="/tmp/output`date +%m`_`date +%d`_`date +%y`.txt"
        touch $OUTPUT_FILE
        marker=""
        num_passed=0
        num_failed=0
        while read p; do
                if [[ $p == *"√"* ]]; then
                        if [[ $p == *"PASSED"* ]]; then
                                num_passed=$((num_passed+1))
                        elif [[ $p == *"WARNING"* ]]; then
                                num_failed=$((num_failed+1))
                        fi
                elif [ $num_passed -gt 0 -o $num_failed -gt 0 ]
                then
                        echo "second branch"
                        echo "$marker PASSED: $num_passed, WARNING: $num_failed" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
                        marker=$p
                        num_passed=0
                        num_failed=0
                else
                        marker=$p
                fi
        done <"$RESULTS_INPUT_FILE"

        # Add un-added lines
        if [ $num_passed -gt 0 -o $num_failed -gt 0 ]
        #if [ \( "$num_passed" -gt 0 -o "$num_failed" -gt 0 \) -a \( -z "$marker" \) ]
        then
                echo "$marker PASSED: $num_passed, FAILED: $num_failed" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
        fi
        echo $OUTPUT_FILE
}
```

because I get errors like

```
/tmp/run_tests.sh1.7381.tmp: line 1: Validation: command not found
/tmp/run_tests.sh1.7381.tmp: line 2: 2017-04-20: command not found
/tmp/run_tests.sh1.7381.tmp: line 3: Login: command not found
/tmp/run_tests.sh1.7381.tmp: line 4: $'\E[1': command not found
```

The words "Validation", "2017-04-20", and so on, are all contents of the file.  What's the correct way to pass in the file path as an argument and not have it be interpreted literally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line for calling your function:

```
output_file=create_test_results_file "$TFILE1"
```

This will assign the value `create_test_results_file` to the variable `output_file` before running the command `"$TFILE1"`.

I believe you might have wanted to do

```
output_file=$( create_test_results_file "$TFILE1" )
```

This assigns the output of `create_test_results_file "$TFILE1"` to the variable `output_file`.

---

There are several things one could comment upon in this script, but I'll pick this line:

```
OUTPUT_FILE="/tmp/output`date +%m`_`date +%d`_`date +%y`.txt"
```

This is better written as

```
OUTPUT_FILE=$( date +"/tmp/output%m_%d_%y.txt" )
```

Also related:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)